# Python Merge sort without slicing

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

Ive attempted to write a quick sort implementation without using slicing but I'm running into problems with halfway through runtime - was wondering if anyone could show me where I'm going wrong

I've added a few print statements (commented out) so you can see whats happening before and after each stage:

```
def mergesort(arr, l, r):

    #print('start: ', arr[l:r])

    if len(arr[l:r]) <=1:
        return arr[l:r]

    mid = l + (r-l) // 2
    left    = mergesort(arr, l, mid)
    right   = mergesort(arr, mid, r)

    l_idx = l
    r_idx = mid
    final = []

    while l_idx < mid and r_idx < r:
        if arr[l_idx] <= arr[r_idx]:
            final.append(arr[l_idx])
            l_idx+=1
        else:
            final.append(arr[r_idx]) 
            r_idx+=1


    for val in arr[l_idx:mid]:
        final.append(val)

    for val in arr[r_idx:r]:
        final.append(val)

    #print('final: ', final[l:r])
    #print()
    #print()
    return final 



    print(merge([0, 9, 3, 7, 4, 2, 6, 1], 0, 8))
```

The values I'm getting show that for the left had side it works well but for the right it doesn't. which is curious because it seems to work for the right hand side of the left...

The stdout is:

```
start:  [0, 9, 3, 7, 4, 2, 6, 1]
start:  [0, 9, 3, 7]
start:  [0, 9]
start:  [0]
start:  [9]
final:  [0, 9]


start:  [3, 7]
start:  [3]
start:  [7]
final:  []


final:  [0, 3, 7, 9]


start:  [4, 2, 6, 1]
start:  [4, 2]
start:  [4]
start:  [2]
final:  []


start:  [6, 1]
start:  [6]
start:  [1]
final:  []


final:  []


final:  [0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 9, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you never use the `left` and `right` lists you get returned from the recursive calls, yet you need these, as `arr` has not changed a single bit by those calls. And when you correct this, you should also be aware that this resulting list will start at index 0, independent of the value of `l` which you passed via the recursive calls. So this means the actual merging loop needs to start at index 0, not `l`.

Here is the code you should have right after the recursive calls:

```
# concatenate the left and right results into arr
arr = left + right

# realign the indexes with the new arr
mid -= l 
r -= l
l_idx = 0
r_idx = mid
```

With this change [it will work](https://repl.it/Fov6).

NB: You said you want to do this without slicing, but note that you still slice: whenever you use the `:` notation, like `arr[l:r]`, you slice.

Comment: Thanks so much, could you please explain the logic of realigning the indices please, the 'mid -= ' and r -=l ' thanks.

Comment: Well, `l:r` is the range in `arr` you are working on, but the returned `left` and `right` lists do not reflect this information any more. `left + right` still has `r - l` elements, but they don't start at index `l` any more, but at index 0 (obviously). So all indexes you use from then on should be `l` units less. That is what `-= l` does: subtract `l` from the left-side name.